# Extracting data from a Rhapsody Table View using Rational Publishing Engine

Tags: tableview, rhapsody, ibm-rational

I am producing a document using Rational Publishing Engine which need to extract information from Rhapsody. I looked into several sources of information about their integration (e.g. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27035704&aid=1), but it's not clear to me how to extract data from Rhapsody's Table View. I know that is possible to obtain an image of the table, but I need to access structured data.

I managed to extract all of the other information I need, but I am not able to identify which of the child node of the TableView rhapsody data source in RPE represents the elements of the table, or if such a node exist.

Is this operation possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you can iterate over the Table Views you have and then print each cell with the columns available in that View (which are defined by a given Table Layout).

So you could end up creating specific Layouts in RPE for each table layout you have... to avoid this, you could use "DataAsXML" which does all for you and allows you to have a generic template. Look for examples here: http://merlinscave.info/Merlins_Cave/Models/Entries/2017/5/26_RPE_Templates_for_Reporting_on_Harmony_Models.html

Comment: Thank you, when I asked the question I didn't have access to the latest versions of RPE and Rhapsody, I should have written which version I were using. Rhapsody 8.1.5 did not export in its XML the DataAsXML property for table views, but only a "contained elements" with the GUID of elements in the table, which made the extraction logic quite annoying.

Comment: Question: I am currently using the "DataAsXML" property of the table view, but it seems Rhapsody has issues on exporting data cells which contains special characters, such as a semicolon. In particular, for a given cell, it exports only the text up to the first semicolon. Is there any way to customize Rhapsody behaviour for the computation of the "DataAsXML" property?

Comment: hi, would you please put this as a new question? it will be more visible...

Comment: Sure, I'll post a new question as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Might have found the solution myself. The problem is that there are no data inside the TableView object, except its scope and layout. So it is my understanding that you have to replicate the same query used in the table view / layout given the scope, using RPE.

For example, if you try to get information about objects contained in a diagram, you find nothing but the GUID of these object: so you need to perform a query from the root of the project searching for elements with the same GUID to access all of the related information.